# Is the index calculation for memory access done at runtime?

Tags: arrays, c

In a code that I'm developing I'm using 1D arrays for storing 2D or 3D data structures. This means that there is a need to make some computation for accessing the array and I was wondering to what extent this calculation affects the clock cycles needed to access the memory.

An example is the following:

```
  for(int k=0; k<OUTPUT_FEA; k++){
    for(int i=0; i<VAL_N; i++){
      for(int l=l_min; l<l_max; l++){
        for(int j=0; j<INPUT_FEA; j++){
          var32 = weights[k*VAL_K*INPUT_FEA+(l-i+VAL_K/2)*INPUT_FEA+j]);
        }
      }
    }  
  }
```

In theory to access the value in memory the index of the *weights* array would have to be calculated and this would involve calculating 3 multiplications, 3 additions, 1 subtraction and 1 division for each loop. Would it be better to calculate the base address before the last for loop and then use it by adding it to *j* ?

Comment: You *could* put temporary variables inside each loop to calculate the partial terms that depend on each loop index ... but a decent optimizing compiler will likely do that for you, anyway.

Comment: ... an example for the outer loop would be to add a `k_term = k*VAL_K*INPUT_FEA;` statement at the beginning of the outer loop and then use `k_term` in the index calculation. You could do similar stuff for the other loops, but some would be more sensitive than others.

Comment: ... also, the calculated `VAL_K/2` doesn't change **at all** so that could be made into a `vkby2 = VAL_K/2` before all the loops. (Division is a very time-expensive operation!)

Comment: @AdrianMole yes, this is what I was thinking but would it be worth it ? how do i know if the compiler performs optimization ? Usually I use GCC with the flag -O3

Comment: I would imagine that GCC with `-O3` will optimize its code far better than anything you could do manually, possibly also using vectorization and/or loop unrolling.

Comment: well, it is often true but not always, that the compiler can optimize better than you. However this *is* a well-known compiler optimization and the compiler probably already does it. It is called strength reduction.

Comment: @Dresult " Would it be better to calculate the base address before the last for loop and then use it by adding it to j" --> when you profiled code performance using that, how was it different that what is posted?

Comment: @Dresult Consider `k*VAL_K*INPUT_FEA+(l-i+VAL_K/2)*INPUT_FEA+j` --> `(k*VAL_K + (l-i+VAL_K/2))*INPUT_FEA + j` to reduce 1 multiplication.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I didn't do the profiling because the final program is long and to analyze the number of instructions executed line by line callgrind requires the -g flag and so I can't compile with the optimization flag.
Anyway, thanks, I hadn't noticed the common factor.

Comment: The answer is compiler specific.  If you don't want to profile the code then generate optimized assembly and see what your does.